# How to find number of unique strings in a column followed by position of a given string

Tags: shell, awk, uniq

I need to do get 2 things from tsv input file:

1- To find how many unique strings are there in a given column where individual values are comma separated. For this I used the below command which gave me unique values.

```
$awk < input.tsv '{print $5}' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Input file example with header (6 columns) and 10 rows:

```
$cat hum1003.tsv
p-Value Score   Disease-Id  Disease-Name    Gene-Symbols    Entrez-IDs
0.0463  4.6263  OMIM:117000 #117000 CENTRAL CORE DISEASE OF MUSCLE;;CCD;;CCOMINICORE MYOPATHY, MODERATE, WITH HAND INVOLVEMENT, INCLUDED;;MULTICORE MYOPATHY, MODERATE, WITH HAND INVOLVEMENT, INCLUDED;;MULTIMINICORE DISEASE, MODERATE, WITH HAND INVOLVEMENT, INCLUDED;;NEUROMUSCULAR DISEASE, CONGENITAL, WITH UNIFORM TYPE 1 FIBER, INCLUDED;CNMDU1, INCLUDED  RYR1 (6261) 6261
0.0463  4.6263  OMIM:611705 MYOPATHY, EARLY-ONSET, WITH FATAL CARDIOMYOPATHY    TTN (7273)  7273
0.0513  4.6263  OMIM:609283 PROGRESSIVE EXTERNAL OPHTHALMOPLEGIA WITH MITOCHONDRIAL DNA DELETIONS,AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT, 2 POLG2 (11232), SLC25A4 (291), POLG (5428), RRM2B (50484), C10ORF2 (56652)   11232, 291, 5428, 50484, 56652
0.0539  4.6263  OMIM:605637 #605637 MYOPATHY, PROXIMAL, AND OPHTHALMOPLEGIA; MYPOP;;MYOPATHY WITH CONGENITAL JOINT CONTRACTURES, OPHTHALMOPLEGIA, ANDRIMMED VACUOLES;;INCLUSION BODY MYOPATHY 3, AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT, FORMERLY; IBM3, FORMERLY   MYH2 (4620) 4620
0.0577  4.6263  OMIM:609284 NEMALINE MYOPATHY 1 TPM2 (7169), TPM3 (7170)    7169, 7170
0.0707  4.6263  OMIM:608358 #608358 MYOPATHY, MYOSIN STORAGE;;MYOPATHY, HYALINE BODY, AUTOSOMAL DOMINANT    MYH7 (4625) 4625
0.0801  4.6263  OMIM:255320 #255320 MINICORE MYOPATHY WITH EXTERNAL OPHTHALMOPLEGIA;;MINICORE MYOPATHY;;MULTICORE MYOPATHY;;MULTIMINICORE MYOPATHY MULTICORE MYOPATHY WITH EXTERNAL OPHTHALMOPLEGIA;;MULTIMINICORE DISEASE WITH EXTERNAL OPHTHALMOPLEGIA    RYR1 (6261) 6261
0.0824  4.6263  OMIM:256030 #256030 NEMALINE MYOPATHY 2; NEM2   NEB (4703)  4703
0.0864  4.6263  OMIM:161800 #161800 NEMALINE MYOPATHY 3; NEM3MYOPATHY, ACTIN, CONGENITAL, WITH EXCESS OF THIN MYOFILAMENTS, INCLUDED;;NEMALINE MYOPATHY 3, WITH INTRANUCLEAR RODS, INCLUDED;;MYOPATHY, ACTIN, CONGENITAL, WITH CORES, INCLUDED  ACTA1 (58)  58
0.0939  4.6263  OMIM:602771 RIGID SPINE MUSCULAR DYSTROPHY 1    MYH7 (4625), SEPN1 (57190), TTN (7273), ACTA1 (58)  4625, 57190, 7273, 58
```

So in this case the string is gene name and I want to count unique strings within the entire stretch of 5th column where they are separated by a comma and a space.

2- Next, the order of data is fixed and is arranged as per column 2's score. So, I want to know where is the gene of interest placed in this ranked list within column 5 (Gene-Symbols). And this has to be done after removing duplicates as same genes are being repeated based on other parameters in rest of the columns but it doesn't concern my final output. I only need to focus on ranked list as per column 2. How do I do that? Is there a command I can pipe to above command to get the position of given value?

Expected output:
If I type the command in point 1 then it should give me unique genes in column 5. I have total 18 genes in column 5. But unique values are 14. If gene of interest is *TTN*, then it's first occurrence was at second position in original ranked list. Hence, expected answer of where my gene of interest is located should be 2.

```
$14
$2
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for adding your efforts in form of code in your question. Please do add samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Please do add your samples into your question in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, my Input file has 6 columns: **p-Value Score Disease-Id Disease-Name Gene-Symbols Entrez-IDs**
So my data is ranked by second column which is score. However, the entries in fifth column (gene-symbols) has multiple entries in some rows and hence I could not do a simple remove duplicate function in excel. Expected output is counting unique genes in fifth column and also identifying the rank of my candidate gene in that column once I have removed the duplicates. eg. of an entry in fifth column is "LTBP4 (8425), DMD (1756), TPM1 (7168)"

Comment: Comments are not meant for writing samples, request you to please add samples in your question in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm absolutely new to SO. Not sure how to add CODE TAGS. But I just edited my post. Is it informative enough now?

Comment: Kindly check this link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks once for CODE TAGS understanding.

Comment: `are comma separated` - didn't you post tab separated file? Och so this: `COL12A1 (1303), COL6A1 (1291), COL6A2 (1292), COL6A3 (1293)` is the 5th column. And now you want to count unique strings within 5th column that are separated by a comma and a space? So for the input it would be 4? `find the position of one particular gene` - what is a definition of "position of a gene"? `of one particular gene` - which one? Can you post like 10 lines of input and show how would you do it on paper for those 10 lines and what the output would be for those 10 lines?

Comment: @stg, Thanks for adding samples in CODE TAGS but still not clear how are you getting expected output, please do explain the logic in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @Ravinder & Kamil, Thanks for your feedback. I've edited my input and output examples furthermore.